# check for undefined with useSelector hook in Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

In my React-Redux project I pretty often need to address state properties using `useSelector` hook from the components. Sometimes some properties lie pretty deep and are accessed with many dots, like these:

`const chosenFriends = useSelector(state => state.friends.chosenFriends)`

or

`const addressComment = useSelector(state => state.actions.address.addressComment)`

The question is how to check for `undefined` (for example if any part of state, let it be *actions* or *address* is not fetched from backend, is undefined and brakes the app).

I chose for this purpose the optional chaning operator:

`const addressComment = useSelector(state => state.actions?.address?.addressComment)`

Is it a good approach or not and what better practices could you offer?

Answer (score 0):

What I ususally do in those situations is hold a variable indicating the current state of the redux, it can be for example:

- Not loaded
- Partially loaded
- Fully Loaded

From this I can choose to load more information into my redux store, so that I know that the information will be there when I render my component. This also allows a clearer way of interpreting the current state of the store. Also, you can use this state variable to render a loading circle if the state is not `Fully loaded`.

If the component you are trying to render needs more information than `Partially loaded`, then simply dispatch in the store that you need more informations, you could have a look at [thunks](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk), it will allow you to achieve asynchronous modifications on the store, such as GETing an API.

If you think this is too much for what you are trying to achieve, this notation ain't bad, but you'll have to check if this variable is `undefined` or not and then display this loading circle